# how do I disable outlook intercepting Ctrl+F7 on windows?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

In visual studio on Windows 10, one of the convenient things to do for compiling a specific file is to hit Ctrl + F7. However, every time I hit that now, outlook email pops up and I can't figure out how to change that in the settings.

Does anyone know how to disable this in outlook? Neither the outlook built-in help nor the interwebs seem to have any information about how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use AutoRuns and boot into a minimal boot configuration.  Does the shortcut still open Outlook?

Comment: Ctrl + F7 did nothing in my Outlook 2016 on Windows 10. Do you have any custom shortcut key in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL + F7</kbd> is not one of the Outlook default shortcuts. And even if you set it (for one of the categories), it will not lead to the described behavior. Quick Steps requre <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

It all looks like you have some add-in installed that incorrectly handles keyboard shortcuts. To check this, exit Outlook and then start it safe mode: `outlook.exe /safe`. If it helps, restart Outlook and disable add-ins one by one to find the faulty one.